# How to apply median function to multiple columns or vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, frame, median

```
df1
vec1 vec2 vec3
0     10   5
10    20   13
20    30   28
```

I would like to create a new column as shown below that contains the median value of a list of vectors in the data frame at its row index.

```
df1
vec1  vec2 vec3 median
0     10   5    5
10    12   13   12
20    30   28   28
```

Comment: `df1$median <- apply(df,1,median)`

Comment: @scoa what if I only want to apply this to vectors 2 and 3?

Comment: `df1$median <- apply(df[,2:3],1,median)`. But the median of two values does not make a lot of sense...

Comment: @scoa thanks. I know I will be applying it to several columns that aren't always the first or last in the data frame. I didn't want to stray too much with the question though. This answers everything.